# Implementing a pseudo random function in practice

Tags: pseudo-random-function

Can anyone point me to a C++ crypto library with an implementation of a pseudo random function (PRF)? I don't have much background in crypto theory, but I am in the middle of a graduate course introducing applications of crypto, so I have a basic understanding of the tools available to me. The research paper I am implementing calls for use of the following cryptographic primitive:

- A pseudo random function $G: \{0,1\}^k \times \{w_1,...,w_m\} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^k$

To clarify, the function $G$, takes as input a private key of length $k$, and a variable length message $w$ (which just happens to be from a finite list of $m$ keywords; I don't think that's important here), and returns output of length $k$.

Now I understand that a block cipher or hash function is to be used in the implementation, but I know it's not as straightforward as "hash(K+w)" and I can not find a technical specification for "pseudo random function" anywhere (e.g., NIST). I come across similar terms all over the place, e.g., pseudo random number generator (PRNG), but I can't definitively connect the two.

I'm not looking for a theoretical connection here (although feel free to include one). I'm hoping someone can point me to a function that gets used in practice for this this situation.

Comment: [HMAC](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html)-SHA256 is "a function that gets used in practice for this this situation." $\;$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So just to verify, you are saying that HMAC (and I'm assuming CMAC) can be used interchangeably with PRF (assuming the underlying hash function / block cipher is "secure")?

Comment: No, I'm saying that for most hash functions (even MD5), HMAC is believed to be a PRF. $\:$ I do not know whether something similar holds for CMAC, although there is [another construction](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-songlee-aes-cmac-prf-128-03) that's _based on_ CMAC. $\:$ Every PRF with large output space is a MAC, but if there is a MAC then there is a MAC that is not a PRF. $\;\;$

Comment: AES-128 also considered good PRF

Comment: @sashank: AES-128 with a fixed key is a PRP over $\{0,1\}^{128}$; as such, we can expect to distinguish it from a PRF with about $2^{64}$ encryptions, and that's not a "good PRF".

Comment: Have you tried the NIST defined PRNG's and looked for libraries implementing those?